# Access to a class method from assembly

Tags: c++, gcc, assembly

I was trying to code the bases of an OS with C++. In order to manage interruptions, I had to write a few asm lines which uses external C++ code declared in asm with `external name_of_the_function`. I put one of these function in a class, but I don't know how to access a class method from the assembly (`external Class::method` doesn't work). The only way I found to do it is creating a function who calls the class method instead, but is it possible to access directly to the method from the assembly ? (assuming these methods are static)

Comment: You might want to look up *name mangling*: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling

Comment: Have a look at Agner Fog's [calling conventions](http://www.agner.org/optimize/calling_conventions.pdf) guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Look into your C++ object file to find the mangled symbol name for the function you want to call.
2. Declare that mangled function name `external` or `global` or whatever syntax you need for your assembler in your assembly file.
3. Call it as you would a C function (you might need to find a `this` pointer if it's an instance method).

Comment: 3. (remembering to pass `this` as the first parameter for the function)

Comment: @Massa - I think my answer already says that.  Maybe you're seeing a cached version?  Besides that, if it's a static (class) method as the OP says, there's no implicit `this`, is there?